# Regex for finding CSS colors in strings (including alpha values)

Tags: css, regex, string, colors

I'm trying to identify CSS color values in strings. Not only hex, but rgb and hsl as well, I've found these throughout different stack posts:

```js
const hexRegex = /#([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){3}(([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){3})?\b/
const hslRegex = /hsl\((\d+),\s*([\d.]+)%,\s*([\d.]+)%\)/g
const rgbRegex = /rgba?\(((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{1,2}|\d\d?)\s*,\s*?){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{1,2}|\d\d?)\s*,?\s*([01]\.?\d*?)?\)/
```

The **rgbRegex** is able to match `rgb()` colors as well as `rgba()` colors, while the **hexRegex** can match solid colors `#000` and `#000000` but it will not match colors with alpha values like `#0000` and `#00000000`. Similarly, the **hslRegex** can match `hsl()` but not `hsla()`.

Is there a way to write the **hexRegex** and the **hslRegex** such that they also match colors with alpha values?

It would also be great if the **hslRegex** could parse out the individual hue, saturation and lightness (and alpha) values when using the JavaScript `.match()` method, which is what the **rgbRegex** does.

Comment: Just a comment, I think you can use `[a-fA-F0-9]` instead of `([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9])` to simplify it a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regular expressions. Note that the regular expressions make use of the `i` flag to match any lowercase and uppercase variants. These have full support for the formats outlined in [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value) (I'm too lazy to go through all of the CSSWG docs).

#### Hex

`#RGB[A]` or `#RRGGBB[AA]`

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/RS3uAs/2)

```
#[a-f\d]{3}(?:[a-f\d]?|(?:[a-f\d]{3}(?:[a-f\d]{2})?)?)\b
```

#### HSL

`hsl[a](H, S, L[, A])` or `hsl[a](H S L[ / A])`

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/RS3uAs/7)

```
hsla?\((?:(-?\d+(?:deg|g?rad|turn)?),\s*((?:\d{1,2}|100)%),\s*((?:\d{1,2}|100)%)(?:,\s*((?:\d{1,2}|100)%|0(?:\.\d+)?|1))?|(-?\d+(?:deg|g?rad|turn)?)\s+((?:\d{1,2}|100)%)\s+((?:\d{1,2}|100)%)(?:\s+((?:\d{1,2}|100)%|0(?:\.\d+)?|1))?)\)
```

If your language permits regex recursion (this is shorter):

```
hsla?\((?:(-?\d+(?:deg|g?rad|turn)?),\s*((?:\d{1,2}|100)%),\s*((?2))(?:,\s*((?2)|0(?:\.\d+)?|1))?|(-?\d+(?:deg|g?rad|turn)?)\s+((?2))\s+((?2))(?:\s+((?2)|0(?:\.\d+)?|1))?)\)
```

#### RBG

`rgb[a](R, G, B[, A])` or `rgb[a](R G B[ / A])`

```
rgba?\((?:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d{1,2}|(?:\d{1,2}|100)%),\s*(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d{1,2}|(?:\d{1,2}|100)%),\s*(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d{1,2}|(?:\d{1,2}|100)%)(?:,\s*((?:\d{1,2}|100)%|0(?:\.\d+)?|1))?|(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d{1,2}|(?:\d{1,2}|100)%)\s+(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d{1,2}|(?:\d{1,2}|100)%)\s+(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d{1,2}|(?:\d{1,2}|100)%)(?:\s+((?:\d{1,2}|100)%|0(?:\.\d+)?|1))?)\)
```

If your language permits regex recursion (this is shorter):

```
rgba?\((?:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d{1,2}|(?:\d{1,2}|100)%),\s*((?1)),\s*((?1))(?:,\s*((?:\d{1,2}|100)%|0(?:\.\d+)?|1))?|(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d{1,2}|(?:\d{1,2}|100)%)\s+((?1))\s+((?1))(?:\s+((?:\d{1,2}|100)%|0(?:\.\d+)?|1))?)\)
```

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/RS3uAs/6)

Comment: this is nearly perfect! thank you! but it seems like the second match in the hsl regex is the full "hue, saturation, lightness" string, was it meant to be simply the "hue" value? the same way that the third matches the saturation value and the fourth matches the lightness?

Comment: @NickBriz you're right, sorry about that - fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another `(,\s*[\d.]*)?` right before the closing bracket which makes the alpha value optional.

```
const hslReges = /hsl\((\d+),\s*([\d.]+)%,\s*([\d.]+)%(,\s*[\d.]*)?\)/g
```